# Invoke Method Receiver?

Tags: java

I have a method in my `MainClass` that returns an integer value. 
I send this method to another Class, which tries to invoke this method. Like this:

```
newVal = (Integer) calcM.invoke(receiver, start+i);
```

But I don't know what to put as `receiver`? `this` doesn't work.

Comment: receiver has no type - I just put in the word "receiver" so you know where it should be. 
invoke is a method to apply on reflected methods to another class. It expects receiver to be Object

Comment: I saw that at second glance, when i realized calcM is already the reflected Method :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case `receiver` is the Receiver object that will get it's method called.

Think of it like this, when you say `myObject.myMethod`, that calls `myMethod` on `myObject`.  It's the same with invoke, it needs to know which object to call the method on. So in this example, You would pass `myObject` into invoke.

Comment: but sometimes there is no object, right?
You can also do something like 
val = getValue();
and there is no receiver object

Comment: in that example you just gave.  `this` is the object being called.  and you would pass `this` to the invoke method.

Comment: No. That would be just short for `this.getValue()` - that was in response to Tobias ...

Comment: but "this" doesn't work - like I said. At least it seems not to work; maybe there's a larger mistake somewhere else in the code.

Comment: I didnt say to use `this` for your receiver, just in your little example.  In your real code, you need to pass in the object whose method needs to be called.

Comment: And how do I declare this?

Comment: You need to pass/store the receiver `Object`.  Then when you call the `invoke` method use it.  I'm pretty sure you define your receive objects somewhere, just make sure you pass them to the invoke method

Comment: Oh, now it works! I had to give `this` from the parent-class to child so it can use this object as receiver. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

What your question suggests look like, your `receiver` would be like:

```
   Method receiver = MainClass.class.getMethod("methodOfMainClass", int.class);
```

Sounds like your method `calcM.invoke`'s signature is like,

```
 public Integer invoke(Method method, int number)
```

So can call,

```
  newVal = (Integer)calcM.invoke(receiver, start+i);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your method is static, the correct receiver is `null`. Otherwise, it is the object you want to call the method on.